# In Jest: In setupTestFrameworkScriptFile, can I access the name/filename of the current executing test file

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

In many of my tests, I create a new slqite database and want to use the name of the test file as the sqlite DBname. This way, all my DB tests are isolated from each other.

As a related question: I would like my setupTestFrameworkScriptFile to be able to read config items (an Object) from the test. Is there a standard way to pass these configs from test to TestFramework?

Here is an example:
In `myclass.test.js`:

```
// "tell" the setup file I'm named 'myclass'
global.testId = function () {
  return "myclass"
}
```

In `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
// if the test supports this method
if (typeof testId === 'undefined') {
    return
}
// create an sqlite DB with that name
_createAndSyncDb(testId)
```

Instead I would like the code in `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` to *read* the filename from the Jest environment, removing the need for the test and setupTestFrameworkScriptFile to both know about a previously *agreed upon* method named `testId`.